# Property Expansion in DataSink

Tags: groovy, ready-api

I'm trying to write test results to a time stamped file in ReadyAPI. I have a DataGen that creates the timestamp in the first step and then later in the DataSink, I use that timestamp in the filename of the out file. I've heard that Property Expansion is allowed in DataSinks but my file isn't being created.

Do I need to initialize and create the file first (Groovy Script)?

**Out File Configuration in DataSink:**    `C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/Projects/xxx/TestResults/OutFile_${DataGen#time}.xlsx`

**DataGen Config:**
[image]

[image]

**Test Steps**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
The last run's timestamp is being used in the datasink. So let's say these are the runs: 
Run 1: **8:00:00 AM** -> Timestamped value ?? 
Run 2: 8:15:00 AM -> Timestamped value **8:00:00 AM** 
Run 3: 8:30:00 AM -> Timestamped value 8:15:00 AM

It seems like the datasink is left with the last cached version of the property and this doesn't get updated BEFORE the new run begins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with timestamps or file creation at all. The issue was trying to use a property expansion in the DataSink. The only way to use a timestamp as the filename is to create it in the **Test Case TearDown Script**. This ensures that all outfiles are closed and no locks are in place.

To fix this problem, use a temp file to write to during the test - in the DataSink. Then in the TearDown Script, create your timestamp, create the new out file, and write the contents of the old file to it.

Here is the Groovy script I ended up using:

```
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def timestamp = ''
timestamp = new Date().format('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss')

def tempFile = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('tempFile')

def output = tempFile +"_" + timestamp + ".xlsx"
tempFile += ".xlsx"

new File(output) << new File(tempFile).bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

That is strange.

If `DataGen` step isn't doing anything other than *timestamp* creation, then I would suggest to try the following:

- Replace `DataGen` step with `Groovy Script` test step.
- Have the below script content into the `Groovy Script`.

```groovy
def dateTime = new Date().format('yyyy_MM_ddHHmmss')
def fileName = "C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/Projects/xxx/TestResults/OutFile_${dateTime}.xlsx"
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('DATA_SINK_FILE_PATH', fileName as String)
```

- And for the file name, please use - `${#TestCase#DATA_SINK_FILE_PATH}`

Comment: Thanks, definitely a step in the right direction. Something weird is happening though.. Please see update

Comment: Glad to that helped. And that proves property expansion works. `DataGen` we can't fix as it's not our hands. And I believe that this answer helps to proceed further while achieving the desired functionality. So appreciate if you can accept it as answer.